# Testing method in angular resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-promise

I am writing the test case for  testing a service call in angular. I am returning a variable value in the resolve. My issue is that i am getting an undefined value as a response after the promise is resolved. following is the piece of code i am using.

```js
        resolve: {
    peopleData: ($q, service, apiOperations, errorService) => {

      const getHelloWorld = () => {
        {
          return‘ hello - world ';
        }
      };

      const errorHandler = (error, operation) => {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        errorService.handle(error, operation);
        deferred.resolve({});
        return deferred.promise;
      };

      service.getPeopleName().then((response) => {
        console.log('called then method');
        if (!angular.isUndefined(response)) {
          return response;
        } else {
          return {};
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        errorHandler(error, apiOperations.GET_PEOPLE);
        return {};
      });

    }
```

Now my test case is

```js
describe('state peopleService application', function() {
  let $q, authService, $state, state_name = 'main.application',
    result, $rootScope, applicationService;
  let errorService = {
    handle: function(error, operation) {}
  };
  let apiOperations = {
    GET_People: ‘getPeople ',
    TEST_ERROR: 'testError'
  };

  angular.module('mock.Service', []).service('mockPeopleService', function() {
      var peopleService = {};
      peopleService.getPeople = function() {
        let deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(‘dummy response ');
          return deferred.promise;
        }
        return applicationService;
      }); beforeEach(angular.mock.module(home)); beforeEach(angular.mock.module('mock.Service')); beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function(_$q_, _$state_, _mockPeopleService_, _$rootScope_) {
      $q = _$q_;
      $state = _$state_;
      $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      peopleService = _mockPeopleService_;
    })); it('should load the data', () => {
      let state = $state.get(state_name);
      let result = state.resolve.peopleData($q, peopleService, apiOperations, errorService);
      $rootScope.$apply();
      console.log('result  ' + result);

    });


  })
});
```

The log.console is returning result undefined

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in an arrow function with {curly braces}, a `return` needs to be explicit, just like in regular functions. So with `resolve.peopleData()` as currently written, `undefined` is hardly surprising.

Adding a `return` and tidying, you might end up with something like this :

```
resolve: {
    peopleData: ($q, service, apiOperations, errorService) => {
        return service.getPeopleName().then(response => {
        ^^^^^^
            if (angular.isUndefined(response)) {
                throw new Error('response is undefined');
            }
            return response;
        }).catch(error => {
            errorService.handle(error, apiOperations.GET_PEOPLE);
            return {};
        });
    }
}
```

Now, the test stands at least a chance of working.